# how to compare multiple values in object in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have data in the following format

```
{
    "monday": "Mon 9 - 12 2 - 4",
    "tuesday": "Tue 9 - 12 2 - 4",
    "wednesday": "Wed 9 - 12 2 - 4",
    "thursday": "Thur 9 - 12 2 - 4",
    "friday": "Fri 9 - 12 2 - 4",
    "saturday": "Sat 9 - 12 2 - 4",
    "sunday": "Sun 9 - 12 2 - 4"
  }
```

but I want to display like this ex: **mon-sat : 9-12 2-4**

Comment: Did you mean `mon-sun: 9-12 2-4` ?

Comment: What's the expected json?

Comment: What is the issue you're having? This isn't a free code writing service. You should make an attempt and if you have problems, ask about them.

Comment: Hey, what is your actual question?

Comment: here i have each day timings but i want to group similar timings and display that accordingly.

Comment: Do you have not so homogenous openning hour and edge case. What if one day have more than 2 open period but it's equivalent to an other? Some day have the same , some day don't, do we group by openning hour, or you join consecutive day with same openning hour?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method `getDaysFormatted` that will receive the two days you want as parameters `day1` and `day2`

Code:

```js
const weekDays = {
  "monday": "Mon 9 - 12 2 - 4",
  "tuesday": "Tue 9 - 12 2 - 4",
  "wednesday": "Wed 9 - 12 2 - 4",
  "thursday": "Thu 9 - 12 2 - 4",
  "friday": "Fri 9 - 12 2 - 4",
  "saturday": "Sat 9 - 12 2 - 4",
  "sunday": "Sun 9 - 12 2 - 4"
}

const getDaysFormatted = (day1, day2) => {
  const d1 = weekDays[day1].split(' ')
  const d2 = weekDays[day2].split(' ')
  return `${d1[0].toLowerCase()}-${d2[0].toLowerCase()}: ${d1[1]}-${d1[3]} ${d2[4]}-${d2[6]}`
}

// Test
[
  {
    day1: 'monday', 
    day2: 'friday'
   },
  {
    day1: 'monday', 
    day2: 'sunday'
  }
].forEach(({ day1, day2 }) => console.log(getDaysFormatted(day1, day2)))
```